# How to send data to controller from test using jest?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, url, controller

I have the following controller w/ sign-up functionality:

```
    // ".../controller.js"
    
    import mongoose from 'mongoose';

    const route = Router();

    export default (app: Router) => {
        app.use('/auth', route);

        /**
         * API-Route for user signup & registration process
         * @param phone phone number of user
         * @param password password of user
         * @param dob dob of user
         * @param name name of user
         * @param gender gender of user
         * @return uid of user and message
         * */
        route.post(
        '/signup',
        middlewares.multer.single('photo'), // multer middleware for getting profile photo
        celebrate({
            body: Joi.object().keys({
            phone:
            password:
            name: 
            gender: 
            dob:
          }),
        }),

        async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
          /* "Sign-up Service is Called Here to Store in Database" */ 
    }
```

Then, I make a test folder and want to write a test that will call  this controller and pass it the phone,password etc values so that i can see if its storing it in the DB.

###### *NOTE: that i want to send the data from within the code.*

> ###### *"As shown above, the controller is being developed in JavaScript and the database I am using is `MongoDB`."*

###### I tried to do the same thing that was done here...

---

https://www.theodinproject.com/paths/full-stack-javascript/courses/nodejs/lessons/testing-routes-and-controllers

...however, its different from what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0):

```js
var adduser = new User({
    phone: req.body.phone,
    password: req.body.password,
    name: req.body.name,
    gender: req.body.gender,
    dob: req.body.dob,
  });
  adduser
    .save()
    .then((data) => {
      return res.status(200).send({
        status: 200,
        success: true,
        data: data,
        message: "user is inserted",
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return res.status(400).send({
        status: 400,
        success: false,
        err: err,
      });
    });
```

You can store the data with this pattern in the mongoose. but the User after the new keyword is model which we have to create & then import in this file. if you data is stored correctly with out any error then is send response 200 & show the data you can check in postman

Comment: I'll make a new user like this

Comment: var adduser = new User({
        phone: '0345678964',
        password:'123!!@DFSDA',
        name: 'ALEX',
        gender: '0',
        dob: new Date(),
      });  So no use of req /res

Comment: User is model of mongoose

Comment: const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    },
    dob:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        require:true
    }
})
module.exports =  mongoose.model('user',UserSchema);

Comment: yes that is already made. I import it and make a new User instance

Comment: Okk like this const User = mongoose.model("nameof model")??

Comment: import User from '../../../src/models/user';  like this

Comment: import  mongoose from mongoose
var User = mongoose.model("user");